# JQuery / PHP call with AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I've been trying to get this really simple example of using AJAX with JQuery and PHP to work with no luck ([here's the page for the sample](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/)).  I've had a look at quite a few posts with similar discriptions and none have helped...

I've copied the code exactly but my function that should be run on success is never called.  As an experiment, in the call to $.post I commented out the data part ({sendValue:str}) and the JSON part and added an alert into the body of the success function to see if it was called and it was.  So I'm guessing there's something wrong with how I've created my data?  I also tried to display the data returned from the AJAX call in the alert and it came out as 'undeclared' (data.returnValue).

This is a copy of my code, you can see the full example via the link above and also a working example from the author of the tutorial here: http://www.devirtuoso.com/Examples/jQuery-Ajax/

JQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#txtValue').keyup(function(){
                sendValue($(this).val());
            });
        });

        function sendValue(str){
            $.post("ajax.php",
                   { sendValue: str },
                   function(data){
                       $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
                   },
                    "json"
            );
        }
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//Get Post Variables. The name is the same as
//what was in the object that was sent in the jQuery
if (isset($_POST['sendValue'])){
    $value = $_POST['sendValue'];  
}else{
    $value = "";
}

//Because we want to use json, we have to place things in an array and encode it for json.
//This will give us a nice javascript object on the front side.
echo json_encode(array("returnValue"=>"This is returned from PHP : ".$value));

?>
```

HTML:

```
    <body>

    <p>On keyup this text box sends a request to PHP and a value is returned.</p>

    <label for="txtValue">Enter a value : </label><input type="text" name="txtValue" value="" id="txtValue">

    <div id="display"></div>

</body>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:
I rewrote my $.post into a $.ajax with an error function in it.  I'm definitely hitting the error function and the error is a parse error - I'm guessing it's coming from my PHP script when I call json_encode...  here's a screenshot from firebug - anyone got any more ideas?:**

[Screenshot 1 - firebug console](http://postimage.org/image/5h4un2q9z/)

[Screenshot 2 - firebug watch window](http://postimage.org/image/44n5l6suf/)

[image: screen grab of firefox console]
[image: screen grab of watch on error function]

**Thanks for all the help so far by the way, really appreciate it.**

Comment: Have you tried echoing or var_dumping early in your PHP followed by exit to see if your post call is making it to the proper place (ajax.php)?

Comment: @csjohn I'll give that a go now and let you know what happens...

Comment: in your code you have ajax.php - is this the read value ? if not can you please tell us what the real value is ?

Comment: @ManseUK yeah it's the real value.  I just rewrote the $.post call to be a $.ajax call of type 'POST' and gave it a success function and an error function - the alert I added to the success function was hit.  I then tried outputting data.returnValue which should have given me the string returned from the PHP file but it came out as "undefined".  Think I need to sit down with firebug and follow everything through - I'll update on my progress.  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that `var str = $('#txt').val();` would give you an error because `$('#txt')` does not exist, it should be `$('#txtValue')`.

After looking at your code, everything looks as it should, my next step would be trying to debug your code by using some console.debug() in JavaScript and some echo in PHP. I recommend you get Firebug for Chrome/Firefox and if using IE upgrade to IE9 and use their developer tools. Using the mentioned tools will give you a better idea of how your code is executing.

My first step would be to make sure that the keyup is firing:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#txtValue').keyup(function(){
            alert('keyUp');
            sendValue($(this).val());
        });
 });
```

Second step would be to make sure sendValue is firing:

```
function sendValue() {
    alert('sendValue');
    var str = $('#txt').val();
    tmr = null;


    $.post(
        'test.php', 
        { sendValue: str }, 
        function(data) { 
            alert('inside post');
            $('#output').html(data.returnValue); 
        }, 
        'json'
    );
}
```

Comment: Cheers - I can confirm that keyup works and that the sendValue function is called.  The success function of the $.post function is however, not called - I think I need to inspect my PHP... What's the best way to follow the flow of data from JQuery to PHP and back?  Can I watch AJAX messages in firebug?  - sorry if that's a silly question, I never usually stray from my .Net camp!  WHERE'S MY IDE!!??

Comment: Yes, you can deff. see the ajax from Firebug.
Try putting another alert('after tmr = null') after the tmr = null; I think that you are getting an error when you try to access the .val() method of $('#txt') because from the code you posted the $('#txt') does not exist, the actual id of the input field is txtValue, you might have to change it to $('#txtValue').val()

Comment: I think you've misread it - I'm definitely using $('#txtValue') then I'm using $(this).val() in the function for keyup... interestingly I just rewrote my post call to look like this and the function for success fires but the value of data.returnValue is "undefined":

Comment: function sendValue(str) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: { sendValue: str },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.returnValue);

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("SOME ERROR");
                    }

                });
            }

Comment: Try doing inside the success function:
for(prop in data){
     alert(data[prop]);
}
 also try data[0].returnValue

Comment: The for loop goes through loads of stuff - not sure how much of it's relevant.  Indexing into it like an array returns an error. Trying to output just data returns [object XMLDocument].  I'm going to try inspecting the sent and recieved messages in firebug.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M some video explainin how to inspect the ajax messages. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of what your various elements are outputting, I don't think I can tell you what to fix, but this example is similar to yours (although it's an all-in-one PHP file rather than two, as in your example). I also added a 350ms timeout to allow the user to type without having the page do an AJAX request every keystroke. As soon as they pause, it'll fetch the data.

Source to `test.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sendValue']))
{
    echo json_encode(
        array('returnValue' => 
              'Returned: ' . $_POST['sendValue']));
    exit();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>AJAX Sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<div id="output"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tmr = null;

$(function () {
    $('#txt').keyup(function() {
        if(tmr != null)
            clearTimeout(tmr);
        tmr = setTimeout("sendValue()", 350);
    });
});

function sendValue() {
    var str = $('#txt').val();
    tmr = null;

    $.post(
        'test.php', 
        { sendValue: str }, 
        function(data) { 
            $('#output').html(data.returnValue); 
        }, 
        'json'
    );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To anyone who gets here looking for an answer to a similar question:**

I tried a few things to figure out what was going on, debugging the messages etc and everything looked fine.  I then deployed my code to a virtual box running apache and to my web server to see if it was an environmental thing.  My code worked on my web server and on the virtual box.  I then realised that I had two conflicting installs of PHP on my dev system. I'm not sure why but this was causing the problem but rolling them both back and reinstalling WAMP on the dev system did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#txtValue').keyup(function(){ 
        $.post("ajax.php",{ sendValue: str },   function(data){ 
        $('#display').html(data.returnValue); 
    }, 
    "json" 
    ); 
}); 
});
```

Comment: It's not helpful anyway. its functionally equivalent to your example but without the extra function call, and introduces an undefined string `str` instead of using the value from your textbox.